# How to display <input type=''text'> without creating a textbox in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a comment box(textarea) in which the user types something and when he hits enter that thing is automatically displayed in 'comment section'. Now when the user hits submit I'm executing the following code,

```
var comment = $("#commentBox").val();
var commentSection = $("#commentSection");
comment.appendTo(commentSection);
```

By the above code the comment typed by user is dynamically displayed in the `commentSection`. This works fine but when user types something like,

```
<input type='text'>
```

in the comment box then a textbox is created within the comment section. So is there a way through which I could not let this happen?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do a google search on "input sanitization"

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can use `encodeURI(comment)` that may do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert the string to entities. Define this function:

```
function htmlencode(str) {
    return str.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function($0) {
        return "&" + {"&":"amp", "<":"lt", ">":"gt", '"':"quot", "'":"#39"}[$0] + ";";
    });
}
```

Then run the following code when the user hits enter:

```
var comment = htmlencode($("#commentBox").val());
var commentSection = $("#commentSection");
comment.appendTo(commentSection);
```

Answer (score 6):

One way would be to just append the data as [`.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Something like this:

```
var comment = $("#commentBox").val();
var commentSection = $("#commentSection");
commentSection.text(comment);
```

**Edit:** To append to an existing part of the comment, replace:

```
commentSection.text(comment);
```

with:

```
commentSection.text(commentSection.text() + comment);
```

Comment: But this will over-write anything in the box when a second comment is added.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan -- picky, picky.  `commentSection.text(commentSection.text() + comment)`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my bad, I didn't understand the question completely, I have updated my anwser

Comment: +1 for the simplicity of your answer but the expression given by chris97ong helped me for other purposes too.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ,

```
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', comment);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
var commentText = $("#commentBox").text();
```

but this do not clean html tags on your string, additionally you can use a function to do this

```
function RemoveHTMLTags(vals) {
            var regX = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
            var html = vals;
            return (html.replace(regX, ""));
        }
```

and then you use:

```
var finalComment = RemoveHTMLTags(commentText);
```