# Stop text being made HTML unless needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I have the ability for a user to post some text into a message feed. They are able to type whatever they want.

The backend server detects that there are links and other linkable elements (like tagging someone else), then saves these links into a database.

When a user is served up the full list of messages, they get shown what the user has posted, and anything that was meant to be a link is turned into a link

For example someone typed www.foobar.com so the post will show `<a href='www.foobar.com'>www.footbar.com</a>`

This works great, however what if someone types HTML in themselves. First off it will mess with formatting, and secondly it allows users to post their own HTML which can be dangerous for obvious reasons.

I need a way of not turning the text that comes back from the API into HTML unless it was HTML that I intended. However I don't want to STOP someone trying to post HTML, just stop it turning into HTML

Twitter does it correctly. If I post this to twitter

```
<a href='www.foobar.com'>www.footbar.com</a>
```

It will show me exactly what you see there, but the www.foobar.com will be highlighted and clickable.

Although it may not be relevant, I am using a ASP.NET Web API backend and Knockout.JS for the front end

UPDATE

I am using the following code to show the text (knockout JS observables)

```
  <div data-bind="foreach: allMessages">
    <span data-bind="html: theText"></span>
```

Comment: I would approach the problem from the other end. Block any `HTML` input from the user. Otherwise you'll be facing a massive problem prone to all sorts of errors.

Comment: Can you just HTML-encode the text when it's output to the UI?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403468/how-to-display-input-type-text-without-creating-a-textbox-in-jquery/23403574#23403574 might help you

Comment: Strip all HTML from the user when they save without warning. Then only match strings that looks like a URL and save/use those

Comment: I want to avoid blocking the user posting HTML, I just don't want it rendered on the screen. The backend matches only URLs and can do what I want with them (turn into links for example) but the HTML of the user is also turned into HTML

Comment: you must escape the html before your link-upgrading code runs. by the time it gets to knockout, you won't be able to tell what HTML you generated and what the user entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backend code should encode the data coming in. this will change the html tags into text based. 
Example is `<div>test</div>` changes to `%3Cdiv%3Etest%3C/div%3E`. this will prevent data getting into your database that you don't want.

Comment: this is what I was after. My lack of html understanding didn't help but your example set me in the right direction